# Json serialize - memore stream timed out

Tags: c#, uwp

im trying to serialize data from json to C# and everytime it throw exception on memory stream : +       WriteTimeout    'ms.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

It does the same thing with XML

here's code:

```
[DataContract]
public class Svatek
{
    [DataMember]
    public string date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

and here's method

```
    public async static Task<Svatek> GetDnesniSvatek()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var url = string.Format("http://svatky.adresa.info/json");
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Svatek));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        Svatek dnesniSvatek = new Svatek();
        dnesniSvatek = (Svatek)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        return dnesniSvatek;
    }
```

Thanks for all advices

Comment: I would really recommend you the Newtonsoft Package from NuGet. It's common for serialize and deserialize json. Fast, Easy, Works

Answer (score 0):

//Here is what exatcly you need

```
    // Create a request for the URL. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
      "http://svatky.adresa.info/json");
    // If required by the server, set the credentials.
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the content.

    Svatek myObjectSvatek = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Svatek>(responseFromServer );


    // Clean up the streams and the response.
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
```

Comment: You should call `.Dispose()` on `reader` and `dataStream` after using them, although using the [using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) might be cleaner as it takes care of dispose even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The json coming from your site is an *array*. So your code should deserialize to *list* or *array*

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Svatek>));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));

var list = (List<Svatek>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

All your other codes are working fine.....